# Jenkins integration with Okta giving 403 , no valid crumb was included in the request error

Tags: jenkins, http-status-code-403, okta

Currently my Jenkins is using LDAP and it is working fine with LDAP but when I integrate OKTA with Jenkins following the below URL:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000105752-how-do-i-setup-okta-as-identity-provider-in-jenkins-

I am getting an error as "403, no valid crumb was included in the request"

In Jenkins, I have already enabled the option in the "Configure Global Security" that "Enable proxy compatibility", but still I am unable to resolve that error.

My setup is Jenkins is being served with nginx ingress controller in an EKS cluster.